# Copiar HTML e alterar ng-model

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Tenho uma parte de HTML que eu estou duplicando via HTML. Dentro do escopo, porém, o ng-model não está funcionando. O HTML:

```
<html ng-app="App"  ng-controller="Theme" >
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
         <div id="parte1">
              <input type"text" ng-model="teste" value="{{ value }}" />
         </div>
         <div id="modal"><div id="modal_content"></div></div>
     </body>
</html>
```

E no meu JS estou fazendo o seguinte:

```
 $('modal').html($('parte1').html());
```

O valor vai para o input. O input aparece certinho, mas o que eu altero no modal, não altera o meu model.

Comment: Desculpa comentar isso mas, 10 edições já '---' pra que tanta?? eu tava meio mal ontem, cansado e posso não ter escrito mto fluido mas, 10 edições? sahushausshuasa

Answer (score 1):

O angularjs funciona de maneira diferente do jquery por isso tem de largar o pensamento jquery-like e passar a fazer as coisa "the angular way".

No seu caso, penso que pretende "duplicar" o primeiro input dentro do modal. Porém, está a pensar em termos de DOM não de MVC (model, view, controller). Quando cria um modelo, esse modelo está disponível dentro do "scope". Cada modelo pode estar ligado a várias "views".

Por isso, a única coisa que tem de fazer é criar um input novo e fazer binding desse input ao mesmo modelo. Ou seja:

```
<div ng-controller="theme">
  <div id="parte1">
    Parte1: <input type="text" ng-model="teste"/>
  </div>
  <div id="modal">
    <div id="modal_content">
      Dentro do modal: <input type="text" ng-model="teste"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Se alterar o segundo input, o primeiro também altera e vice-versa.

[**PLUNKR**](http://plnkr.co/edit/JSsQ1aUwXWMZpDm0SQDY?p=preview)

---

## nota

Como nota, como se está a iniciar no angular, aconselho a não usar o jquery ao mesmo tempo, para perder os "vicios" do jquery. A mim ajudou-me a fazer as coisas "the angular way" =P

Aconselho também a ler [este artigo (em inglês)](http://joelhooks.com/blog/2013/07/27/using-angularjs-stop-using-jquery-as-a-crutch/)

Comment: certo mas, eu to replicando o input que vai ser aberto no modal e o usuario é que vai digitar o valor no modal... por isso o problema

Comment: e o jquery não ta alterando a variavel, ta só replicando o input que o cara vai informar o valor

Comment: Porque o jquery não altera a variavel, altera o value do DOM Object.

Comment: @CaioGomes O que pretende fazer exactamente? É que não estou a perceber! Explique o que pretende

Comment: eu crio vários campos dinamicamente na hora de montar a tela que vão para um modal, só que esse modal recebe várias coisas, desde alertas a conteúdo, quando eu jogo o contéudo que tem os inputs pro usuário alterar no modal, quando o usuário digita no input, os valores não alteram no model, sendo assim, a edição feita no modal, fica perdida, e eu preciso que o ng-model capture a edição feita no modal, sendo que, o contéudo do modal, é jogado via html() pelo jQuery...

Comment: @CaioGomes Já percebi, veja a minha resposta nova.

Comment: certo mas, eu perciso que o valor do modal seja dinamico, eu não posso iniciar meu html com ele, assim iria funcionar, mas, o conteudo do modal vai mudar, então.... eu preciso de uma solução que eu altero via jQuery por exemplo, e o bind seja feito

Comment: Mas esse modal... está a usar o bootstrap? É que isso que pretende fazer não dá. o Jquery mexe no DOM, não consegue mexer nos modelos do angular.

Comment: sim, estou utilizando bootstrap

Comment: Use antes o bootstrap.ui http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/